# RETURN FALSE failure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a simple procedure I learned from a book in learning jQuery but it doesnt seem to work.

I am trying to load a seperate html page into a DIV when a link is clicked.

My main html page looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>My Page</title>

<script src="_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="_js/myJava.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1>My Name</h1>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li class="wx"><a href="work.html">WORK EXPERIENCE</a></li>
<li class="wx"><a href="education.html">EDUCATION</a></li>
<li class="wx"><a href="skills.html">SKILLS &amp; CERTIFICATIONS</a></li>
<li class="wx"><a href="refs.html">REFERENCES</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="exp">
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My js page has this on it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.wx a').click(function() {
var url=$(this).attr('href');
$('#exp').load(url);
return false;
}); 
});
```

Everytime I click a link though, it directs me to the new page instead of loading it into my "exp" div. Any ideas?

Comment: What you have should work. Check for errors in the console which are stopping the `return false;`

Comment: The most likely cause is jquery not being included properly.

Comment: I am including jQuery as you see it above. Not sure where the issue would be...

Comment: You're including it, but are you including it _properly_? Is that the correct path? Check your error console for errors and the network tab for 404 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  preventDefault(), if that doesn't work either then jQuery isnt loading properly or you have some kind of conflict or error happening. so check the error console.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.wx a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); //prevents default event triggered by clicking on anchor element
var url=$(this).attr('href');
$('#exp').load(url);
});
```

});

Comment: `return false` should be doing what preventDefault() does.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wx a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url=$(this).attr('href');
    $('#exp').load(url);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: `return false` should be doing what preventDefault() does.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to swap out my jQuery file with another verison and it worked. I was using the latest version but when I swapped to 1.7.2 it worked